# Prevent Mobile Safari zoom when navigating between pages

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mobile-safari

I don't like asking this question because I'm fairly certain I know the answer - it can't be done... but I need to find out if anyone has more insight than me.

Is it possible to prevent Mobile Safari from remembering the zoom level either when refreshing a page or navigating back or forwards using the native browser's buttons? I only ask because it has been raised as a bug in QA testing and I think it is a feature of the browser.

I am using this viewport metatag by the way:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=960, user-scalable=no">
```

Any thoughts would be very useful, even if its to confirm my suspicion.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a way to prevent Mobile Safari from remembering the zoom level, I'm pretty sure it's entirely up to the user to un-zoom/zoom on a page upon reload.  Please share if you do find a way, though.

Feel free to report the bug to Apple in the form of a radar submission, or as a feature request!